# Issues to modelize a system of differential equation (NDSolve)

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I've got an issue.
Indeed, I've got the following system:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\mathrm d\tilde{x}}{\mathrm dt}\\\frac{\mathrm d\tilde{y}}{\mathrm dt}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a-by_p(t)&0\\0&er_p(t)-m\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\tilde{x}\\\tilde{y}\end{pmatrix}$$

I first tried to solve it with `DSolve`, but it seems that this system has no solution. (because the integral of $y_p(t)$ have no solution)
Then I tried to use `NDSolve`:
[image]

But I've got the following issue :
"NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`."

I'm sorry if the solution of my issue is obvious, I'm new on *Mathematica* and I tried to fix it for 1 week by searching on the forum ..
Thank you.

Comment: NDSolve needs numerical values for a,b,e and m. Also, the exp and gamma are without capital letter such that mathematica does not recognize them. Try to define (such that the variables are black instead of blue) all your variables exept for x,u and t

Comment: And you can post and format code, not images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention in the comment, you need to specify numerical values for the different parameters when using `NDSolve`. I am still confused about `y` in `yp[t_]`, anyway, I treated it as a parameter too. In `yp[t_]`, you need to replace `exp[]` with the proper syntax `Exp[]`.

```
r = 1; gamma = 1; k = 1; T = 1; e = 1; m = 1; a = 1; b = 1; y = 1;

yp[t_] = y*Exp[e*r*(1 - Exp[-gamma*(t - k*T)])/gamma - m*(t - k*T)]

rp[t_] = r*Exp[-gamma (t - k*T)]

s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (a - b*yp[t])*x[t], u'[t] == (e*rp[t] - m)*u[t],
    x[0] == 1, u[0] == 0}, {x[t], u[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]

Plot[{x[t], u[t]} /. s, {t, 0, 20}]
```